# Run multiple different re.subs against single file in python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

So I have a file that my server generates and I am trying to clean it up and remove the unnecessary extra and different characters that are on the lines, beginning and ending of lines.  Where I get stuck is that I have to create a new file after each re.sub and then delete the old one.  I have about 10 re.subs right now and I feel that creating and deleting files is inefficient.

```
def linecleanup():

    file_in = open('Server.txt', 'r')
    file_out = open ("Server.txt1", "w")
    lines = file_in.read()
    regex = re.sub("\s\s\s\s\<revision>", "Revision: ", lines)
    file_out.write(regex)
    file_in.close
    file_out.close

   os.remove('Server.txt')

linecleanup()

def linecleanup1():

    file_in = open('Server.txt1', 'r')
    file_out = open ("Server.txt2", "w")
    lines = file_in.read()
    regex = re.sub("</version>", " ", lines)
    file_out.write(regex)
    file_in.close
    file_out.close

    os.remove('Server.txt1')

linecleanup1()

def linecleanup2():

    file_in = open('Server.txt2', 'r')
    file_out = open ("Server.txt3", "w")
    lines = file_in.read()
    regex = re.sub("</revision>", " " + '\n', lines)
    file_out.write(regex)
    file_in.close
    file_out.close

    os.remove('Server.txt2')

linecleanup2()
```

Comment: Unrelated: You forgot to call `close` on your files. Code should be `file_in.close()`, not `file_in.close`.

Comment: I forgot to add it when putting in the code.  Good catch though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is not tested but you could do something like this:

```
def linecleanup():

    with open("Server.txt1", 'r') as file_in:
        lines = file_in.read()        

    lines = re.sub("\s\s\s\s\<revision>", "Revision: ", lines)
    # Where a simple find&replace (non-regex) is required, you could just use this instead:
    # lines = lines.replace("</version>"," ")
    lines = re.sub("</version>", " ", lines)  
    lines = re.sub("</revision>", " " + '\n', lines)    

    with open("Server.txt3", "w") as outp:
        outp.write(lines)

linecleanup()
```

Comment: Works perfectly.  Thanks!